# BigQuery clustering per hour

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table into which I stream a few thousand events per hour. Each event has a **time** field containing the timestamp of the event, and the table is partitioned by day on the **time** field.

I'd like to calculate hourly aggregate statistics on the data, once per hour.

If I do that with partitions only, that would not be very efficient, because, for each hourly query, I'd be scanning the whole partition (so, I'd have to scan all the data that was streamed so far in the day, even though I want only the last hour). So I'm considering clustering per hour.

My doubt is: what is generally more efficient? (1) to cluster the **time** field directly? or (2) to have an additional field, **hour**, containing the time rounded down to the hour, and cluster by this new field?

Comment: Generally it's efficient if a single cluster is more then 1GB. Will you reach that with your data volume with `few thousand events per hour`?

Comment: @Pentium10 - In fact, no, the data volume is much smaller than that.

Just to be more concrete, there are multiple tables, each one with a different event count - but currently none of them get a rate of more than 60000 events per hour (which would would reach about 265 MB in a day).

Comment: 265MB in a partition it's extremely small, generally speaking even if you do this additional clustering it will save some something.

Comment: @Pentium10 This probably belongs to another question, but is there any alternative method that you would recommend? Instead of streaming directly into the final table, I've thought of sending it first to a hourly staging table (especially created for that hour), calculate the hourly statistics on top of that, then bring that hour's raw data into the long-term table via a query job.

Comment: that works out well, eventually you can have 1 single large streaming table and a shadow copy as you want. Even you can use the MERGE syntax.

Comment: @Pentium10 - Right now my idea would be to use streaming along with Template Tables to stream into hourly tables (like table_20190305_0100, table_20190305_0200, one for each hour), then somehow I'd have to run a process to query the hourly tables at each hour, do the aggregations (which would be appended to an aggregations table) and then merge the hourly raw data into a larger, long-term table. (But I haven't tried this setup yet due to other projects.)